# Problem in Conditional rendering with react-final-form formState

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-final-form, final-form

Here my react code.

```
<Form
  onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
  initialValues={formInitialValues}
  render={({ hasValidationErrors }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field
         label="First name"
         name="firstName"
         component={TextInput}
         validate={...validate callback function...}
       />
      {hasValidationErrors
        ? <button type="button">Proceed</button>
        : <div>Some Content</div>}
    </form>
   )
/>
```

Using `hasValidationErrors` for my condition but the page keep stucked and throw

> Error code: SIGILL

I found the problem was using formState.

Comment: can you please provide more info,eg what is `hasValidationErrors` look like is it a state,what kind of value are you putting in it and what is the code inside the `onSubmit`and `handleSubmit` function

Comment: I'm using 'react-final-form' library, if you know how to use that, u may understand. Refer: https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/FormState